# how can i restrict users to some specific urls

Tags: python, django

I want to restrict users to access the payment and checkout pages by typing the url in address bar like **"home/shop/checkout/" and "home/shop/payment/"**
I want to make these pages accessible only if either buy_now form is valid or items_buy_now form is valid

> urls.py

```
path('payment/',views.payment,name='payment'),
path('checkout/', views.checkout, name="checkout"),
```

> views.py

```
def checkout(request):
        request.session.pop('data', None)
        messages.success(request,'Done.Thanks for using our services.')
        return redirect("shop:mycart")

        def payment(request):
            return render(request,'shop/payment.html')

        def buy_now(request,slug):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            messages.info(request, 'You have to logged in first.')
            return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
        product = Product.objects.get(active=True, slug=slug)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = BuyerDeliveryForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                buyer = form.save(commit=False)
                buyer.save()
                return redirect('shop:payment')
        else:
            form = BuyerDeliveryForm()
        return render(request, 'shop/delivery_form.html', {'form': form, 'products': product})


    def items_buy_now(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            messages.info(request, 'You have to logged in first.')
            return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = BuyerDeliveryForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                buyer = form.save(commit=False)
                buyer.save()
                return redirect('shop:payment')
        else:
            form = BuyerDeliveryForm()
        return render(request, 'shop/delivery_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to :

1. Create a Mixin that manager either items_buy or items_buy
2. For all the views that have to handle the restriction, subclass it from the respective mixin.
3. In the get function of the subclass call the method to check if the user has the authorization to access to that page.